how to navigate back in flutter webview 4.x.x
i am using foo.com as in flutter webview 4, when i go to foo.com/about it does not go back, popScope apears, how to prevent pop scope if i am on foo.com/about
this is my build method
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
            print(request);
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            controller.runJavaScript(
                "document.getElementsByClassName('logo me-lg-4')[0].style.display='none';");
            controller.runJavaScript(
                "document.getElementsByClassName('tawk-min-container')[0].style.display='none';");
            controller.runJavaScript(
                "document.getElementsByClassName('scrollToTop active')[0].style.display='none';");
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://auctionwind.com'));

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewWidget(
          controller: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

and this is my popscope (in another dart file)
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didpop) async {
        if (didpop) {
          return;
        }
        final bool shouldPop = await onback(context);
        if (shouldPop) {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold()


I don't fully understand your question but to answer the question in your title, WebViewController has a goBack() function to do that

when i click back button on the app exits, where it should not exit, instead it should go to previous page
